Not able to add firebase to my Flutter project
When i run flutter project i got this failure.
I tried to insert firebase into my project.
I did everything according to the instructions from the Firebase site
I have no idea what i have to do.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Settings file '/Users/daniilsereda/StudioProjects/translator/android/settings.gradle' line: 29

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.4.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.4.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

I've tried everything, but nothing works.

You have added firebase i guess? And some configuration for it is not complete. Share your pubspec.yaml, both build.gradle and settings.graddle

@Ultranmus
You can check it here
https://github.com/whitemam8a/Translate-app/tree/main

According to your error and after checking your project i found that some plugin declaration is missing.
Add this
id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.1" apply false
in your settings.gradle
Like below:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.1" apply false
}

Also make your repo private, your credential like api key for firebase project is visible in the github repo.
